# Increment a value in models.py and website behaves accordingly

Tags: python, html, django

I am new to Django and I've got the hang of the basics so far but I am trying to do something that the tutorials I learnt from haven't taught me and basically what I want to do is, I have a field in my models.py called `delegates_num` and that field is a counter for the number of delegates which sign up for a particular course. I want to be able to increment that field by 1 each time someone signs up for a particular course, the courses being `[ITIL, Change Management, Management of Risk, Programme Management, PRINCE2]`

So for example, if the user books an ITIL course, the counter for that course will be incremented by 1. Each course has a limit of 15 spaces so a condition somewhere which says something like:

```
    if course.name = 'ITIL' && if delegates_num > 15
    redirect user to 'course is full page'
 else submit registration form and increment delegates_num by 1
```

I would be extremely grateful for any help, here's the code so far:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    MY_CHOICES = (
        ('Open', 'Open'),
        ('Closed', 'Closed'),
        ('Fully Booked', 'Fully Booked'),
    )
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    course_code = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='add price')
    topic_details = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    start_date = models.DateField('start date')
    end_date = models.DateField('end date')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=MY_CHOICES)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    delegates_num=models.IntegerField()
    def add_delegate(self):
        #for count, thing in enumerate(args):
        self.delegates_num+=1
    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name
```

models.py

```
 <h1>Registration</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

        {% if course.course_name = 'ITIL' %}
            {{ course.delegates_num|inc }}
            {% if course.delegates_num > 15 %}
               <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://example.com">
                     <script type="text/javascript">
                        window.location.href = "https://yr4-group-project-mfblack.c9users.io/sorry_full/"
                </script>
                {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
```

book_course.html

```
def book_course(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StudentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            student = form.save(commit=False)
            student.save()
            student.course.add_delegate()
            return redirect('registration_complete')
    else:
        form = StudentForm()
    return render(request, 'website/book_course.html', {'form': form})
```

views.py

Answer (score 0):

It's probably much easier to just make a property, since I'm guessing you're not taking into account people leaving the course - or the possibility of user error.

A property that retrieves a count is usually a small database operation and has some guarrantee to be accurate

```
@property
def delegates_num(self)
   return self.user_set.count()
```

<sub>I assume you have a fk to a user model or simlar..</sub>

Comment: By adding that into my models.py, every time a user books a course now it will automatically increment this field?

Comment: @HassnIrshaad - No, by doing this you no longer have a need for the field, but you still are able to access its value in the same way in your template `{{ course.delegates_num }}`

Comment: How would I increment this value by 1 in my code? The same way?

Comment: @HassnIrshaad - There is nothing to increment... this gives you a count of the number of users for a given course... (its designed to be a property of the `Course` class)

Comment: I don't think you've fully understood my issue, I have already got a field in my database which stores the number of users per course, what I want to do is every time a user books for a course, increment that field by 1...

Comment: @HassnIrshaad - I don't think you fully understand your model... you shouldnt store the number of users, you should just let your user have a foreign key to a course, then let database queries figure out how many there actually are.

Comment: @HassnIrshaad Keeping a consistent count of the number of related objects (delegates in this case) is a difficult problem. It's way easier to let the database calculate the count dynamically whenever you need it, than to keep your own count synchronized with the actual number of delegates. This assumes that you have a model for the delegates with a foreign key/m2m field to `Course`.

Comment: The delegates do have a foreign key of course in the model